# A bit of recursion, array of characters and strcpy in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion

today I've come across an exercise that I think I didn't fully comprend. Here is it:

```
    typedef struct n { char c[8]; struct n *next; } node;
 
nodo * f( node * x, char * s ) {
  nodo * n;
  if( strlen(s) > 0 ) {
    n = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->next = x;
    strcpy( n->c, s++ );
    n->c[1] = '\0';
    *(n->c) += strlen(s);
    return f( n, s );
  }
  return x;       
} 
 
void printr( node * r ) {
  if( r ) { 
    printf("%s", r->c);
    printr( r->next );
  } 
}
 
int main() {
  char p[] = "AMNG" ;   
  printr( f( NULL, p ) );
  return 0; 
}
```

Now my questions are all about the first call : 
What does   `strcpy( n->c, s++ );` really mean? I read it like ' take the string "MNG" and copy it in n->c. Is it right?

Then we have    `n->c[1] = '\0';` that make n->c (as a string) "M /0 G" .
Also   `*(n->c) += strlen(s);` is not clear. I know what happens if I add a number to a character, but I'm very confused about the use in this specif case.

Thank for the help guys, really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you try to compile it before posting? Do you think this is a [mcve]?

Comment: Great time to learn how to use a debugger. Step through the code and see what happens.

Comment: _Now my questions are all about the first call : What does  strcpy( n->c, s++ ); really mean? I read it like ' take the string "MNG" and copy it in n->c. Is it right?_ Yes, but it also increments `s` because of `s++`. _I know what happens if I add a number to a character, but I'm very confused about the use in this specif case._ It just adds the length of the string to a character. The use case here is just fun, nobody would write a program like this other than for fun.

Comment: So *(n->c) += strlen(s); changes the first letter. I don't understand the result. Is it M+ 3 = P? Michael you are right, my professor is very funny.

Comment: @user7499569 alphabet goes like this "...LMNOPQR...." (remember from 1st grade) therefore 'M' + 3 is 'P'.

Comment: seems like a quite ineffective way to create a list of a characters from a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call `strcpy( n->c, s++ );` simply copies `s` into `n->c` until a null character is found, then increments `s`. It is strictly equivalent to

```
strcpy( n->c, s );
s++;
```

as the post-increment operator `s++` returns the value of `s` *before* incrementing it (as opposed to the pre-increment `++s` which returns the incremented value).
The content of `n->c` is by now `AMNG\0`.

The second line `n->c[1] = '\0'` effectively shortens the copied string to 1-character long, `n->c` equals `A\0NG\0` which, as a null-terminated C string, appears as `"A"`

Last, `*(n->c) += strlen(s)` is equivalent to `n->c[0] += strlen(s)`, as dereferencing an array is equivalent to accessing its first element, thus the ASCII-encoded character `'A'` is added `strlen(s)`, which is 3 and turns `n->c[0]` to `'D'` (see http://www.asciitable.com/).

Now this process is repeated until `s` is empty and nodes are chained backward, each one containing a 1-character string, converting the N-characters string into N chained nodes (in reverse order).